# $_POST of php file doesn't work but $_GET yes. Ajax calls it, returns 200 OK but $_POST into php file is empty

Tags: php

This the AJAX CODE: ("newContent" is "try a connection" in this simple example)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", //i have tried method: "POST" but still not working
        url: "change.php",
        data: {"edit": newContent},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("ERR");
        }
    });
```

This code works, it returns OK and display response (that is empty due to php code). If I look on the network, the "edit" variable is displayed by the php code but if I look for any POST variable inside the code I don't find any. With the GET request, on the other hand, I find everything fine and everything works.
My PHP CODE:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents("example.php"); //Get content of file        
    
    $new = $_POST['edit']; //get post data
    $new = nl2br($new);

    //This change text into file and save it.
    $pageName = explode('/pagine/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $number = $pageName[1];
    $pageName = $pageName[1].".php";
    
    $file_contents = str_replace("TESTO QUI", $new, $file_contents);
    $file_contents = str_replace("988", $number, $file_contents);
    $file_contents = str_replace("Versione ITA:", '<h2 style="color:blue">Versione ITA:</h2>', $file_contents);
    $file_contents = str_replace("Versione ENG:", '<br/>
            <hr>
            <h2 style="color:blue">Versione ENG:</h2>', $file_contents);
    
    file_put_contents($pageName, $file_contents);
}
?>
```

The problem is that if i change POST to GET it works well but if i change to POST it doesn't work anymore. Why?

Can someone help me? Please, i should send to php a very long variable (more than 8 thousand characters) and i absolutely need this post action. Thanks a lot to everyone.

**EDIT:**

- post_max_size into my php.ini is 16M
- file_get_contents("php://input") returns blank only if i put POST to method into ajax
- var_dump($_POST) returns array(0) {}
- var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) returns string(3) "GET" but i don't know why because i have set into ajax POST and into php code request method == POST
- updated ajax calls but still not working

is there anyone very good at these things who can help me? probably the problem is in htaccess but i don't know how to change it

Comment: Does your POST work with small values?

Comment: What is the value of post_max_size in php.ini?

Comment: no, POST doesn't work with small or big values. GET yes instead. In my php.ini i have post_max_size = 16M

Comment: What doesn't work? Do some debug. What's in `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`? What's in `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Maybe you need to get values from `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: var_dump($_POST) return array(0) {}

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])-> return string(3) "GET"    (i don't know why, i said to ajax POST request)

Comment: file_get_contents("php://input")---> returns blank

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is GET when sending POST?

Comment: You need to use `method: "POST"` in ajax

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ---> returns blank

Comment: You need to use method: "POST" in ajax ----> it doesn't work, still not working and returns blank on debug of $_POST["edit"]

Comment: i think the problem is in the htaccess but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: I don't think you want `processData: false` unless you're sending JSON in which case you would need `contentType: 'application/json'`. Try removing those 2.

Comment: done it but still not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

```
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
```

Which leaves the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object to interpret the data you pass it, convert it to a format standard for HTTP and set the right `Content-Type` header in the request.

This is *great* when you pass it a `FormData` object.

You aren't though.

You are passing it a plain object. So it converts it to a string (`"[object Object]"`) and sets a default `Content-Type: text/plain` IIRC).

PHP doesn't know how to handle that type of data and the real data has been lost anyway.

**Don't** set those two directives. jQuery will process the plain object, format the data and set the `Content-Type` for you.